# BigCommerce API - What is correct resource for updating an option value

Tags: api, bigcommerce

I'm trying to update an option value using the BigCommerce api.

The documentation says PUT /options/values/id.json

The console says PUT options/id/values.json

I think it should be PUT options/id/values/id.json, which returns a 200 response code, but does not execute the update.

Any information on what the right endpoint is for this and if it works?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if you do a GET request on options

```
{
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Colors",
        "display_name": "Color",
        "type": "CS",
        "values": {
            "url": "https://store-xxx.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/options/3/values.json",
            "resource": "/options/3/values"
        }
}
```

The resource endpoint shows that the URL is options/id/values.json. But, this gives you all the values associated with the option. If you want to retrieve a specific option  the endpoint is something similar  to /api/v2/options/3/values/7.json

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "option_id": 3,
    "label": "Silver",
    "sort_order": 1,
    "value": "#cccccc"
}
```

Doing a PUT request on this - (On REST console, setting the header content-type to application/json and sending raw JSON data) updates the label - Changed Silver to silver)

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "option_id": 3,
    "label": "silver",
    "sort_order": 1,
    "value": "#cccccc"
}
```